# SQL identical values not matching

Tags: sql, join

I'm experiencing something strange when joining SQL tables.

Let's say I want to output an image for each result where

```
tableA.FullNameA = tableB.FullNameB
```

I am entering the data in table B with a php form. To my human eyes, the names I have are identical in both columns. However, it does not detect a match. If I then manually go into the db and copy and paste the name from `tableA.FullNameA` to `tableB.FullNameB` (and when it is overwritten, there is no discernible change to the text) then it miraculously matches and my join is successful.

Is this something to do with encoding of the data when it is added to the DB? I have never come across this before - does anyone recognise this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Select length of strings.  Compare with trim(). Leading or trailing spaces will confuse you as they look the same.

Comment: TRIM(tableA.FullNameA) = TRIM(tableB.FullNameB) or trim($inputString) in php before INSERT to db (add to cleansing function).

Comment: Thanks both for your help! I have it working now :)